# How can Excel 2007 / 2010 consume a REST web service?

Tags: web-services, excel, rest

What options exist to consume a REST web service from within Excel 2007 / 2010?  I can use XML Maps to consume a basic XML list, but that doesn't let me build a dynamic URL (so I could include parameters).

For example, I can add an XML Map to Excel for http://machine/service/level/5 and display the values in the workbook just fine - no problem there.  The real question is, how can I dynamically change the /5 part of the URL to come from another cell in excel?

That way I can have a couple of cells that have the options (what ID, what name, etc.) and whenever those values change (ideally) a new dynamic URL would be constructed and the XML map would be refreshed.

Is such a thing possible?  Does anyone else have a better way to take some parameters, call a web service (REST or SOAP, I'm not picky) and shove the results back into excel for further manipulation?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903731/book-list-getting-book-details-from-amazon-using-excel-vba-barcode-lookups/3942771#3942771

Comment: I created a excel plugin that can be used to integrate restful APIs with Excel, see http://www.enclout.com/home/ignite

Answer (score 1):

XLLoop (http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/) can be used to call make Json of HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerPivot with Excel 2010.  Download from [here](http://www.powerpivot.com/download.aspx).

From the home tab select 'From Data Feeds', then 'From Other Feeds'.

You should be able to use this to point to your URL.

I've read that PowerPivot uses REST but I haven't tried it myself.

Good luck! :)