# Returning result of an external script to VBA

Tags: python, macos, vba, ms-word

I am working on porting a macro that we have working in MS Word for Windows to OSX. The macro allows the user to generate equations using LaTeX in Word, and has to make a POST request to a server and return the result. This works fine in Windows with the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` object, but there does not appear to be an equivalent in OSX.

To get around this, I have created a Python script that uses `urllib` and `urllib2` to handle the request, and allows me to send my LaTeX string and web address as input arguments using `argparse`. This script does what I need it to, and returns the result from the web query as a string.

I need this string in VBA.

My current VBA call is something like the following, where `pyPath` and `getURLpath` are static, `Latex_Str` and `Font_Size` are generated by user input, and `WebAdd` is the address of the server that is running our server-side script.

```
sCmd = """" & pyPath & "python"" """ & getURLpath & "getURL.py"" --formula """ & _
       Latex_Str & """ --fontsize " & Font_Size & " """ & WebAdd & """"
sResult = Shell(sCmd, vbNormalFocus)
```

The problem is that the `Shell` command only returns the double-valued PID of the process you are calling. I need the actual string returned from my Python script. I can modify the Python script to return this however I want, but how do I get it in to VBA?

Does anybody know how I can get this result into my VBA environment?

Comment: I have been working on implementing this. I am getting an error still, but I think this will probably get the job done in the long run. I will post back here with more information soon if I cannot figure out what is causing my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer extracted from question:

I got it working!
I was able to call my Python script using the `result = MacScript(command)` function where I defined my `command` as the following:

```
command = "do shell script """ & pyPath & "python " & getURLpath & "getURL.py --formula '" _
          & Latex_Str & "' --fontsize " & Font_Size & " " & WebAdd & """"
```

My Python script is called `getURL.py`, and handles the request to the server based on the optional arguments `--formula` and `--fontsize` defined by the user and stored in VBA as `Latex_Str` and `Font_Size` respectively, and the web address of the server `WebAdd`. I also added some functionality to my Python script to handle passing proxy settings. The above command passed through `MacScript` returns the stdout of the Python script, which is the return from the server. The Python script is as follows:

```
# Import the required libraries
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, ProxyHandler, build_opener, install_opener
import argparse

# Set up our argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sends LaTeX string to web server and returns meta data used by LaTeX in Word project')
parser.add_argument('webAddr', type=str, help='Web address of LaTeX in Word server')
parser.add_argument('--formula', metavar='FRML', type=str, help='A LaTeX formula string')
parser.add_argument('--fontsize', metavar='SIZE', type=int, default=10, help='Integer representing font size (can be 10, 11, or 12. Default 10)')
parser.add_argument('--proxServ', metavar='SERV', type=str, help='Web address of proxy server, i.e. http://proxy.server.com:80')
parser.add_argument('--proxType', metavar='TYPE', type=str, default='http', help='Type of proxy server, i.e. http')

# Get the arguments from the parser
args = parser.parse_args()

# Define formula string if input
if args.formula:
    values = {'formula': str(args.fontsize) + '.' + args.formula}   # generate formula from args
else:
    values = {}

# Define proxy settings if proxy server is input.
if args.proxServ:       # set up the proxy server support
    proxySupport = ProxyHandler({args.proxType: args.proxServ})
    opener = build_opener(proxySupport)
    install_opener(opener)

# Set up the data object
data = urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')

# Send request to the server and receive response, with error handling!
try:
    req = Request(args.webAddr, data)

    # Read the response and print to a file
    response = urlopen(req)
    print response.read()

except URLError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):    # URL error case
        # a tuple containing error code and text error message
        print 'Error: Failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):    # HTTP error case
        # HTTP error code, see section 10 of RFC 2616 for details
        print 'Error: The server could not fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
        # print e.read()
```

If anyone is curious, the full code will be available on the [project page](https://github.com/Engineero/latex_in_word) once I am done fixing a couple additional bugs and testing it. The (working) Windows version is already up there.