# F# or C# based Excel add-in on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, excel, f#, add-in

I have some handy Excel add-ins running under Excel on Windows and I would really like to produce versions of the add-ins that will work with Excel on OS X. Under Windows I use the fantastic Excel-DNA package to allow me to invoke my .Net based logic from VBA. However, on my Mac I'm really struggling to even find a start point when it comes to writing, packaging, deploying and then calling a C# or F# based add-in.

Alternatively is there some non-VBA I can rewrite my add-ins so they will run on both Windows and OSX? I'm open to Scala, Python or anything else that gives me the desired portability.

I can see a post on here from 2011 and so I'm writing in the hope that things have progressed since the last query of this type in 2011.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no difference from the old threads - It's VBA only still...

Comment: why not go in the opposite direction-- instead of calling an external lib from vba, control excel with an external application.

Answer (score 7):

The development language, and whether or not you use Mono (to run C#/F#), is not really at issue. If there were some support for native (xll-style) add-ins in Excel for Mac, it would be possible to bind that to anything else, as I've done with [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) under Windows. Ancient (pre-OS X) versions of Excel for Mac did support native .xlls, but I have found no documentation or evidence that this is still supported.

Binding from VBA to external code, in the style of COM or `Declare Function` might be possible - certainly you can use `Declare Function` to call .dylib libraries (I say that based solely on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15994195/44264)). So that gives you one direction to explore, and Xamarin for Mac might allow you to create native libraries that will work with `Declare` in C#/F#.

I have never been able to find much documentation for Excel for Mac online, which rather discourages further effort.

---

All this is a long way to say that for power users, Excel is pretty much Windows-only. Your efforts are probably best spent exploring virtual machine or dual-booting set ups.

I'd welcome any information to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem with [ExcelDNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/).  As stated in the ExcelDNA forums it does not support Mac for Office, however there is a workaround.  Install Wine for OSX and then run Microsoft Office 2003 or 2010 within it.  I used a commercial distribution of Wine called [Crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/products2/?utm_expid=4394146-2.b7_vwUKxROqdYmz7or_Oqg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.hk%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CB0QFjAA%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.codeweavers.com%252Fproducts%252F%26ei%3DrlvTVMDwBsHtmQXHuoEg%26usg%3DAFQjCNFymN6m0AWqJg0b5OrN4FQByRc_dw%26sig2%3DRNQqOYTq1EHfQHzUZi_2Kw) and it works well.  The downside of this approach is that you must install Wine on every target for your AddIn.

The Excel AddIn I created is [Excel-REPL](https://github.com/whamtet/Excel-REPL).

Comment: Neat. What do you use it for?

Comment: @JohnZabroski I used it at a bank until I got fired.

Comment: Banks tend to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not F#/C# but there is a Scripting Bridge that allows you to access some of the [Excel OM using Obj-C](http://www.oatmealandcoffee.com/applescript/scripting-bridge/). You could also go the [VBA route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx#UsingVBAToCreateAddins_CreatingVBAAddinFiles) and perhaps [call your C# libs from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6)?