# Is it possible to run Jruby/Celerity scripts via Excel VBA and output the results to Excel

Tags: ruby, excel, vba, jruby, celerity

I have some Jruby/Celerity scripts that I would like to run from Excel VBA and then output the script results to an Excel sheet.  Is this possible?  Can anyone suggest a potential approach or some potential resources.

What I'm hoping to achieve:

1. Mac Excel 2011 VBA code calls Celerity script and passes parameter that will be used by the script.
2. Script executes, utilizing parameter passed by VBA.
3. Script complete its execution and returns results to excel worksheet.

EDIT: I should also mention that I am running Excel 2011 on a Mac. One of my areas of confusion is that everything I have found on automating Excel with ruby seems to assume a Windows operating system. (# Require the WIN32OLE library).  Would I use the same library running excel under OS X.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to run a random jruby script and getting the response back in a cell?

Comment: No, I have not. I have been working with the shell command in VB and based on some things I've seen on the web I thought it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution by example

### simpletest.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "celerity"

word_to_search = ARGV[0]
word_to_check = ARGV[1]
#puts "DEBUG - word_to_search: #{word_to_search}"
#puts "DEBUG - word_to_check: #{word_to_check}"
browser = Celerity::Browser.new
browser.goto('http://www.google.com')
browser.text_field(:name, 'q').value = word_to_search
browser.button(:name, 'btnG').click
puts browser.text.include? word_to_check
```

Suppose we have to interface **Excel 2011 on a Mac** with this simple script that takes a couple of input parameters and returns a result

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash --login
rvm use jruby > NULL
ruby simpletest.rb $1 $2
```

We write a shell you can invoke via VBA code; 
Please be aware to set proper permission  `chmod u+x test.sh` 
The shebang: `#!/bin/bash --login` this is required in order to run `rvm` to select jruby ( that is the only ruby supported by `celerity`

### VBA Module ( User Defined Function )

```
Public Function SimpleTest(sWordToSearch, sWordToCheck)
    Dim sCommand As String
    sCommand = "do shell script ""cd /Users/ronda/projects/so-test1; ./test.sh "
    sCommand = sCommand & sWordToSearch & " "
    sCommand = sCommand & sWordToCheck & """"
    SimpleTest = MacScript(sCommand)
End Function
```

Note in this code: `/Users/ronda/projects/so-test1` is the path to our scripts

### Usage & Testing

#### Testing the User Defined Function in a formula

[image: SimpleTest User Defined Function Usage]

Btw the diagnosis of problems may be streamlined by running the script to a lower level:

#### Testing in the AppleScript edtor[image]

#### Testing the shell script in terminal

```
$ cd ~/projects/so-test1  
$ ./test.sh Ruby Language
true
$ ./test.sh Fish Language
false
```

#### Testing the jruby script standalone

```
$ rvm use jruby
Using /Users/ronda/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11
$ ruby simpletest.rb Ruby Language
true
$ ruby simpletest.rb Ruby Fish    
false
```

### further reading

Just a couple of useful link:

1. read this answer to [How do I issue an HTTP GET from Excel VBA for Mac 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15994195/1657028) as an alternative (*possibly the most powerful*) approach using [popen and pipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/popen.3.html)
2. [Accessing Your Custom
   Functions](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut01.htm)

Comment: Franco - Thanks for a great response to my question.  Cheers.