# "ActiveX can't create object error 429" on CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to call a function which utilizes the Bing Maps API.

```vb
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String, key As String)

    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String

    firstVal = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&travelMode=driving&o=xml&key=" & key & "&distanceUnit=mi"

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    url = firstVal & start & secondVal & dest & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.Send ("")
    GetDistance = Round(Round(WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(objHTTP.ResponseText, "//TravelDistance"), 3) * 1.609, 0)  End Function
```

I got it to work on Windows.

On Mac I get

> error 429
> ActiveX can't create object

on:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

I tried:

```
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

I added all the references that are available.

Comment: `Server.CreateObject`  - maybe if you were using vbscript in ASP...  `CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")` works fine for me.

Comment: Are you working on a Mac?

Comment: BigBen yes I am.

Comment: MS = Microsoft....

Comment: BigBen right what would I put instead of MS? Mac?

Comment: I tried it on a windows machine and I get the error: "can't compile"

Comment: [Perhaps useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211124/http-get-request-using-vba-in-osx-excel).

Comment: Its not still the same error

Comment: On windows what does `debug.print objHTTP.ResponseText` show in immediate window

Comment: Seems its an operating system issue, got it to work on Windows

Comment: if anyone has a solution for Mac it would be greatly appreciated