# Visual Basic Activx-Component can't create object ( MacOs )

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm currently trying to make a http request from vba ( Excel ) to a slack channel, where I get value from specfic cell and send the value to slack, for MacOs I get error, Activx-Compoent can create object, is there a way to fix this issue, or an alternative to make this possible?

```
Sub SendToSlack()
    Dim http As Object
    Dim webhookUrl As String
    Dim strData As String
    Dim cellData As String
    
    ' Set your webhook URL
    webhookUrl = "WEBHOOK_URL"
    On Error GoTo ErrorHanlder
        ' Retrieve the value from a specific cell with specific format
        cellData = Format(Sheets("SHEET_NAME").Range("CELL_NAME").Value, "$##,##0.00")
        
        ' Create HTTP request object
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
        ' Prepare the JSON payload
        strData = "{""text"": """ & "Total yearly costs: " & cellData & """}"
        
        ' Send the HTTP request
        http.Open "POST", webhookUrl, False
        http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        http.send strData
        
        ' Check if the request was successful
        If http.Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Error sending message to Slack: " & http.responseText
        Else
            MsgBox "Message sent to Slack successfully!"
        End If

        ' Clean up
        Set http = Nothing
        Exit Sub
ErrorHanlder:
    MsgBox Error.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: afair activex is windows only technology

Comment: `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` is going to be a problems since that `MS` is for `Microsoft`

Comment: Maybe something like outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211124/http-get-request-using-vba-in-osx-excel would help out.