# how to do OAuth authentication using Mac Excel VBA

Tags: vba, macos, excel, oauth

Excel Mac do not support CreateObject method so cannot use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP and similar objects.

Simple HTTP post example using Querytable I got from this answer [How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba/4617566#4617566)

For OAuth authentication, I think HTTP headers has to be posted to server, Can this be done using QueryTable ? is there any other way to do OAuth authentication in MAC Excel ?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess the only way is make XHR with credentials for authorization, then make another XHR to retrieve the necessary data, and parse the response. Please share the URL and data you need to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for comment. will that work in mac excel ?

Comment: Actually I'm not quite familiar with Mac, seems some workaround is necessary to make XHR in Mac, check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15981960/2165759).