# Using curl within Mac VBA to send a file via HTTP POST

Tags: excel, vba, shell, curl

I'm trying to send an image file via curl via Mac Excel VBA.  I've gotten great help from [How do I issue an HTTP GET from Excel VBA for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981960/how-do-i-issue-an-http-get-from-excel-vba-for-mac) and I have most of it working.  I can send data via post and get server responses.
However, the code fails when I try to upload a file.
Here is an example of a curl string which executes perfectly from the Terminal app:
`curl -H "apikey:helloworld" --form "file=@/Various/ImageTest/Puzzle2.smaller.jpg" https://api.ocr.space/Parse/Image`
Note the pathname has to start with an "@" and the top level is the root directory. Also the image file is an image on my Mac, but if you try to test the above just point to any image file on yours.
The server responds to the above.
However, when I take the same code and I put it into VBA it fails.  I am succeeding in everything other than loading a file.  But when I try to upload a file I get a code 6656 returned and nothing else.  I don't believe the 6656 is coming from the server, I think it's coming right from my Mac.
Here is an example

```
Sub RunTest2()
    Dim result As String
    Dim exitCode As Long
    Dim Stringtest As String
    Dim StringToSend As String

    StringToSend = "curl -H 'apikey:helloworld' --form 'file=@/Various/ImageTest/Puzzle2.smaller.jpg' https://api.ocr.space/Parse/Image"
    result = execShell(StringToSend, exitCode)
    Debug.Print "Result: " & result
    Debug.Print "Exit Code: " & Str(exitCode)
End Sub
```

The execShell routine above is the same one from [How do I issue an HTTP GET from Excel VBA for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981960/how-do-i-issue-an-http-get-from-excel-vba-for-mac).  Here is that code:

```
Option Explicit

' execShell() function courtesy of Robert Knight via StackOverflow
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136798/vba-shell-function-in-office-2011-for-mac

Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String, ByVal mode As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function pclose Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function fread Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal outStr As String, ByVal size As LongPtr, ByVal items As LongPtr, ByVal stream As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function feof Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Function execShell(command As String, Optional ByRef exitCode As Long) As String
    Dim file As LongPtr
    file = popen(command, "r")

    If file = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    While feof(file) = 0
        Dim chunk As String
        Dim read As Long
        chunk = Space(50)
        read = fread(chunk, 1, Len(chunk) - 1, file)
        If read > 0 Then
            chunk = Left$(chunk, read)
            execShell = execShell & chunk
        End If
    Wend

    exitCode = pclose(file)
End Function

Function HTTPGet(sUrl As String, sQuery As String) As String

    Dim sCmd As String
    Dim sResult As String
    Dim lExitCode As Long

    sCmd = "curl --get -d """ & sQuery & """" & " " & sUrl
    sResult = execShell(sCmd, lExitCode)

    ' ToDo check lExitCode

    HTTPGet = sResult

End Function
```

Thinking that maybe the problem was with string format, I've tried double-quotes, single quotes, and ascii chr(34), but nothing changed.  Ii also tried the ascii for the @ sign.
If I remove the @ then I do get a response from the server but the response is that the "file" parameter is wrong.
Somehow the file is not being loaded correctly, even though the same code works from Terminal.  I am thinking that it could be a permissions issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer.  It does appear to be a sandbox/permissions issue.  I have not figured out how to get around the sandbox (or even if that would be a good idea, though there should be some way to make a folder permissible).

However, I found that there is a folder that Excel uses internally, and if I make a folder within that folder and put image files in it, the above code executes perfectly.

The pathname to the folder is "/Users/USER NAME/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office."  This folder is exempt from the permissions restrictions that were causing the code to fail, and I believe is in every Mac Office configuration.

I still would like to know if there is a way to make any given folder permissible.