# Shell call from Excel VBA freezes - involves MacScript and Python (Excel for Mac 2011)

Tags: python, macos, vba, excel

This macro runs fine on Excel 2011 for Mac:

```
Sub Works()
    scriptToRun = "do shell script ""/anaconda/bin/python -c "" & quoted form of ""import test_file"" "
    res = MacScript(scriptToRun)
    Debug.Print res
End Sub
```

The according `test_file.py` file (place it somewhere on the pythonpath) is:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

However, when I involve the `appscript` Python package, it freezes for a very long time and does nothing. Change the `test_file.py` file to this (`pip install appscript` first):

```
import appscript
app = appscript.app('Microsoft Excel')
app.cells['A1'].value.set(2)
```

But when I run the command directly from the AppleScript Editor, this works:

```
do shell script "/anaconda/bin/python -c " & quoted form of "import test_file"
```

How can I call this from Excel VBA on Mac? (By the way on Windows, it works easily with `WScript.Shell` and `pywin32`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the `system()/popen()` call from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320294/918626) and run the command as background process with an ampersand at the end:

```
Private Declare Function system Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long

Sub RunTest()
    Dim result As String
    result = system("/anaconda/bin/python -c 'import test_file' &")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code compatible with Excel 365 for mac? Tonite i will try it

Comment: As long as you're staying in the sandbox, it should still work, but otherwise you may need to use the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949272/the-macscript-function-is-not-working-well-in-office-for-mac-2016-any-ideas/30949324#30949324

Comment: yes thx for your help

Comment: Solved for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670317/how-execute-python-directly-from-excel-vba-mac/77677521#77677521