# Send data in HTTP Post from VBA Excel for Mac and Windows

Tags: excel, vba, http, https, webforms

I'm not a programer,I would like it to put in data and then pull down the results in a area of the Excel sheet.

1. Fill in text box1(by ID) with info from cell M1.
2. Fill in text box2(by ID) with info from cell M2.
3. Select (examples male, female and other(by ID))from an "option selector” with info from cell M3.
4. click the button submit.
5. Pull data from a textbox(by ID) after the website has stopped loading and put the data in cell M10.

Since it should work on both then I need an if-statement to tell what computer it's on(Mac or Windows).

I can do it on windows but excel can't do it on mac due to that internet explorer is on a option I can install.

so the best thing would be to have it just fill in and get info without opening a browser at all.

Can anyone help?
If possible to provide the code or a start at least. running excel 2011 on mac but if possible to run if tor windows and later versions of excel as well for both mac and windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963099/send-data-in-http-post-from-vba-excel-for-mac

Comment: Is there a way to have it detect if it is running on a mac or a pc(windows)?

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac001.htm

Comment: I don't understand how do do this?
There is so much code I don't understand.
as I understand it all I need is to read from the sheet and then fill in something on a website then pull the data down. Should I really need to run throw shell and so on?

Comment: Thanks for the links but I need some more help to understand

How would the code look like? 

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to hire someone for this.  I doubt anyone is going to provide you a full solution.  I don't have a Mac so I can't help there.

Comment: Like I said I don't need a full solution I just need a start. I can do most of it just not the go to website part