# Curl POST in Excel for Mac (VBA) Version 15.29.1

Tags: vba, excel, curl

I need to do a series of [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) calls from Excel running on a Mac (version 15.29.1).

I found some [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136798/vba-shell-function-in-office-2011-for-mac) as below, however I keep getting:

> Runtime error 5 (Invalid procedure call)

Can anyone here help with a solution?

Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

' execShell() function courtesy of Robert Knight via StackOverflow
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136798/vba-shell-function-in-office-2011-for-mac

Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String, ByVal mode As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function pclose Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function fread Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal outStr As String, ByVal size As LongPtr, ByVal items As LongPtr, ByVal stream As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function feof Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Function execShell(command As String, Optional ByRef exitCode As Long) As String
    Dim file As LongPtr
    file = popen(command, "r")

    If file = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    While feof(file) = 0
        Dim chunk As String
        Dim read As Long
        chunk = Space(50)

        read = fread(chunk, 1, Len(chunk) - 1, file)
        If read > 0 Then
            chunk = Left$(chunk, read)
            execShell = execShell & chunk
        End If
    Wend

    exitCode = pclose(file)
End Function

Function HTTPGet(sUrl As String, sQuery As String) As String

    Dim sCmd As String
    Dim sResult As String
    Dim lExitCode As Long

    sCmd = "curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d """ & sQuery & """" & " " & sUrl
    MsgBox (sCmd)
    sResult = execShell(sCmd, lExitCode)

    ' ToDo check lExitCode

    HTTPGet = sResult

End Function
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?