# How do I get a website IP Address in Excel using VBA? For Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ip-address

On a Mac OS, I'm trying to figure out how I can get the IP address of a website like 'www.google.com' and add it into a cell in Excel. I've written a Visual Basic Macro script that loops through every row of a spreadsheet and takes the value of column 2 (the website URL). My spreadsheet looks like this:

```
|----------|-------------------|--------------|
| [Button] | Website           | IP Addresses |
|----------|-------------------|--------------|
|          | www.gov.uk        | <ip_address> |
|          | www.parliament.uk | <ip_address> |
|----------|-------------------|--------------|
```

I would like to put the corresponding IP Adress of the website URLs in column 2 into column 3. I've tried to write a couple of examples but I get a few errors:

**Example 1**

Shows an alert that says "Runtime error '424': Object required".

```
Sub GetIPAddresses()
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) = False Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = System.Net.Dns.GetIpAddress(Cells(i, 2).Value)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Example 2**

Shows an alert that says "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined".

```
Sub GetIPAddresses()
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) = False Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = GetIpAddress(Cells(i, 2).Value)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: do you have 64 bit version of Excel?

Comment: @Zam I just checked and yes, I'm using a 64-bit version of Excel.

Comment: You cannot just paste VB.NET code into VBA and expect it to work.

Comment: @GSerg Sorry, I'm new to Visual Basic, not really sure how things work and just wanted to create a spreadsheet that converts website URLs to IP addresses. Do you know what I can do to make my script work please?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074533/canonical-how-to-call-net-methods-from-excel-vba

Comment: I have big doubt about .Net support in Excel for Mac OS X

Comment: How about using xmlhttp to call a Web API?

Comment: Hi @Kevin, how can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.google.com.co/amp/s/officetricks.com/domain-to-ip-find-website-ip-address/amp/

Comment: Here is an article on how to call a Web API from Excel: https://codingislove.com/excel-json/

Comment: I like @RicardoDiaz answer.

Comment: Here is a [VBS script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6114bbe9-5cca-402c-a903-036818bd5537) which also works

Comment: @JoshuaWaheed can please add to question subject information that you need this to be done for Mac OS X. It's really very important.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look into this tonight. I've been developing on a mac and have no Windows machine to test these on. I'll also have a test of the XmlHttpRequest version and will get back to you guys on what worked or didn't work for me.

Comment: @Zam That's now done.

Comment: Then you should also remove the tag winapi

Comment: @Storax That's also done now.

Comment: I think your best be is going to be to run a shell command and collect the output. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320294/4088852) covers how to shell on a Mac (the code linked in prior comment uses `WScript`, which I highly doubt will work). As far as the command to use, I'm not familiar with Mac command line utilities, but I'm guessing it is similar enough to Linux that it will have `ping`. After that, it's just a matter of parsing the output.