# VBA Excel Runtime Error 53 Accessing Shell

Tags: excel, vba, macos, shell, sh

I am trying to run a Shell script from Excel using VBA. The Terminal prompt I to run the script is `cat "prompt.csv" | sh runScript.sh "WSO"`. The following code attempts to run that line, but I run into an

> Error 53: File Not Found

Any help is much appreciated!

```vb
Sub Run_Jar()
    ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Shell "cat 'prompt.csv' | sh runScript.sh 'WSO'"
End Sub
```

The possible duplicate is for Office 2011, but I am using Office 2016. I need parameters, so `Shell()` does not work, `MacScript()` [is an outdated command](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/applescripttask.htm), and I cannot find `libc.dylib` on my machine.

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure, how can I check?

Comment: @taurus Is there a bitten apple on the outside of the case?

Comment: Yes, there is..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Shell function in Office 2011 for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6136798/11683)

Comment: @GSerg None of those solutions worked.

Comment: This is excel for mac? If so please add the necessary tag to your post

Comment: Are both files (`prompt.csv` and `runScript.sh`) in the same folder as your workbook? Does this command run `cat 'prompt.csv' | sh runScript.sh 'WSO'` when you run it in a terminal in the path of your workbook?

Comment: Yes, the files are in the same folder. That prompt does work correctly from terminal. I found a solution using AppleScript, but it involves copying a script to Excel's script folder. I would like to distribute this workbook, so that is not an ideal solution.

Comment: I've never worked with Apple but I assume the syntax is similar to Linux's bash: have you tried: 1) to add `./` in front of the file name (e.g. `./prompt.csv` and `./runScript.sh`)? When calling a shell from code, it doesn't have the same context than calling it via the UI console.; 2) if that doesn't work, have you tried to add full path of the files? (in Linux would be `/folder1/folder2/folder3/prompt.csv`)? Still the same principle of the context which is missing in a runtime shell and is not in a UI shell...

Comment: You need to ChDrive first to make sure the drive is active. If its still error, after chdir try print the current directory and append the current directory to the file name.