# Excel VBA Macro to query Amazon Web Services for Book data

Tags: vba, amazon-web-services, title, isbn

I have an .xcl with 500 books, title in one column, author in another.
I want to query amazon web services with a vba macro to pull back amazon's listing with title, author, isbn, and most importantly publisher and year.

[Book list - getting book details from amazon using Excel VBA barcode lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903731/book-list-getting-book-details-from-amazon-using-excel-vba-barcode-lookups)

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Using-the-Amazon-Web-Service

These have me on the right path, but one searches by isbn's, and the other i dont understand.

I have very little programming experience, but am a fast learner so what do I need to do to get this to work? Otherwise I have to go line by line and search amazon individually. 
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to solve this issue:

http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/Artigo.aspx?id=448

http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/449/Obtendo-dados-atualizados-da-Web-atrav%C3%A9s-do-Excel-XP-Parte-2Consumindo-Web-Services-no-Office.aspx

The articles are in Portuguese, but I believe that you can read it using Google Translate.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Easier way would be to use automation software that offers web data extraction capabilities. Look at Automation Anywhere. You can probably set up the task and schedule it within a few minutes. Hope this helps.
-Tom

Answer (score 0):

The ISBNDB API lets you search by keyword, ISBN, author or publisher.

http://isbndb.com/docs/api/

Given your search criteria, it returns title, author, ISBN, and a host of other information.