# MVC compatible Grid, which will have Excel functionality

Tags: model-view-controller, excel, grid

In our project we need to implement Excel-like grid for web, which will look and fell like Excel cells(not fully, but as much as it possible for web).
 The most important functionality, which we need, is ability to input formulas in cells (and they could be like "=A1+C4") 
Aspose.Cells looks good, but it is not compatible with MVC at all. Only with ASP.Net. And ASP.Net is not a good way to go, as large part of our system is already working and is based on MVC.

Any help\experience will be appreciated.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a long way with jQuery (jsGrid) but if you want your users to use excel why not just let them?

Excel supports Restful data

Some reading:

[How can Excel 2007 / 2010 consume a REST web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250186/how-can-excel-2007-2010-consume-a-rest-web-service)
[Book list - getting book details from amazon using Excel VBA barcode lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903731/book-list-getting-book-details-from-amazon-using-excel-vba-barcode-lookups/3942771#3942771)
http://libkod.info/officexml-CHP-9-SECT-5.shtml
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937697.aspx
http://blog.tonysneed.com/2010/04/13/wcf-data-services-versus-wcf-soap-services/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907578.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7609